# C# accessing folder/files thru webservice

Tags: c#, file, web-services, directory

**How can I have a webservice read/browse a folder content ?**

For instance this type of code:

```
    FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowser;
    folderBrowser = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();

    folderBrowser.Description = "...";
    folderBrowser.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
    folderBrowser.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
```

When I build the solution I get this error...

> The type or namespace name
>   'FolderBrowserDialog' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

I know it doesn't make a lot of sense trying to use a dialog in a webservice but how else can I do it?

My webservice receives a string and then I want to browse for files that contain that string in a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `System.IO` namespace to navigate into your filesystem; as you noted, doesn't make sense trying to display a dialog on a webservice call.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles.aspx). Displaying the FolderBrowser dialog can naturally only be used with thick client interactive WinForms apps.

Answer (score 1):

Use a StreamReader to read a text file:

```
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filename);

string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();

reader.Close();
```

To list files in a folder:

```
 DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(fullPathToFolder);
 FileInfo[] fileList = di.GetFiles("*.aspx");

 foreach(FileInfo fi in fileList)
 {
     // do something with fi.Name
 }
```